# Unity 2D: Get the x-axis and width of the rendered UI Image and NOT the values of the rect transform

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas, width, rect

Unity, I have an image that need enable preserved aspect ratio and I need to get the x-pos & width of the image based on how it was rendered in the screen and NOT the Rect Transform values. I hope you understand may problem. How can I get the x-pos and width of this?

[image]

Note: I don't need to use Aspect Ratio Fitter and Content Size Fitter for this situation. I just need those values.

Comment: Can someone explain why this question does not show any research effort or unclear or not useful? I've been researching this whole day and trying to come up with solution. Is this irrelevant question? Please tell me why and not just voting down the question directly.

Answer (score 0):

<s>`.mainTexture.width` will give you the pixelsize and with `.pixelsPerUnit` you can calculate the x poition (assuming that origin in in the middle) and width in units</s>

ignoring the offset that comes with not being at the origin.
your calculation should be something like this:

```
float size = 0;
if ((float)img.sprite.texture.width / transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width <
    (float)img.sprite.texture.height / transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height)
  {
    size = (img.sprite.texture.width * transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height /(float) img.sprite.texture.height);
  }
else
  {
    size = transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width;
  }
float x = size * img.pixelsPerUnit  * transform.lossyScale.x;
```

this calculation should give you the x position (extent) you asked for to get the size you just need to double the value.
Also if an image has a higher width then height you need to add additional cases

Comment: .mainTexture.width will give the exact width size of the image and not width rendered in the screen.

Comment: .mainTexutre.width will give you the pixel size and .pixelsPerUnity the amount of pixels per Unit, if you then calculate in the scaling you should get what you want.

Comment: can you give a C# snippet method code for this? I cannot get the idea how pixelsPerUnit and pixel width size can come up with the solution. Thank you so much for helping out.

Comment: Hey, sorry. I made a mistake by ignoring the image ratio, but `(img.sprite.texture.width / (float)img.sprite.texture.height) * (rect.height / rect. width)* img.sprite.pixelsPerUnit * transform.lossyScale.x` should be correct

Comment: @Techreator any problems?

Comment: sadly I cannot get the correct values. Here's the code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/k0lPvZ02

Comment: you probably need to add the elements world position to it, the calculation i posted is for elements that are @vector3.zero, so if they aren't on that position you have to add the elements world position to the calculation. Also please remember that this calculation just calculates the x value, if the exact position should be at the top left cornor you need to add the y value to it aswell. that should be nearly the same but  switching width and height and changing scale.x to scale.y

Comment: I only tested it with Vector3.zero world position and tested only for x value. I haven't used the code yet beyond its functionality.

Comment: the secont rect.height / rect.width should have a float cast aswell, i forgot to add that, this should create a loss of precision. if you have a rotation this could create a problem aswell and would need to be added in the calculation

Comment: rect.height and rect.width is returning float already so I think there is no need to cast. Also, there is no rotation to any axis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208962/discussion-between-nka-zz-and-techreator).